# alpine aarch64 can not install and run aws-cli v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, arm64

I have an EC2 instance with arch arm64: `aarch64`

I want to install aws-cli v2 on this instance, and I do following the official document of AWS: `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html#cliv2-linux-install`

But after install like above document, I met below problem:

```
bash-5.1# aws
bash: /usr/local/bin/aws: No such file or directory

bash-5.1# ls /usr/local/bin/aws
/usr/local/bin/aws
```

As you can see, I have that file but can not executed.
After find exactle where the bin located, I execute it but it show like this:

```
bash-5.1# ls -la aws
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       4496072 Jun 11 11:41 aws

bash-5.1# ./aws
bash: ./aws: No such file or directory

bash-5.1# /bin/sh aws
aws: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")
```

I have doing exactly the document said for installing aws-cli v2 for arm64 Linux.

```
curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-aarch64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
unzip awscliv2.zip
./aws/install
```

Answer (score 2):

I can not install aws-cli v2 directly, but I have an useful workaround like this:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir awscli
```

Above solution work for me, but first of all, you need to install `pip` before, also its requirement packages.

Comment: this is version 1